# creating array of paragraph in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, paragraph

I'm drawing data in a JS canvas. I need to enter the veritcal and horizontal axis values at fix intervals.

I would ask how to create an array of paragraph or text to assign an absolute coordinate and the right axis value to draw them around the canvas.

[image]

currently I created and edited line by line:

```js
document.getElementById('percent0').innerHTML = 
                         a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
a = minVal+(maxVal-minVal)*0.25;
document.getElementById('percent25').innerHTML =
                         a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
a = minVal+(maxVal-minVal)*0.5;
document.getElementById('percent50').innerHTML = 
                         a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
a = minVal+(maxVal-minVal)*0.75;
document.getElementById('percent75').innerHTML = 
                         a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
a = minVal+(maxVal-minVal)*1;
document.getElementById('percent100').innerHTML = 
                         a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
```

but I would like to use a smart way to do it with array if possible.

thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add mark values to array and use it where it changes:

```js
const marks = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100};

marks.forEach(mark => {
const a = minVal+(maxVal-minVal)*mark / 100.0;
document.getElementById('percent' + mark).innerHTML =
a.toFixed(5-Math.round(Math.log10(a)));
});
```

If you want to create those html elements with code too you can simple have something like `<div id="marks-container;></div>` in your HTML and then add all paragraps with JS too -

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.id = "percent" + mark;
document.querySelector("#marks-container").appendChild(p);
```